# ASP.NET/IIS: Tell IIS do not check for file existence

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my `Global.asax.cs`, I have:

```
routes.MapRoute("AssetCss", "css/{*path}", 
    new { controller = "Asset", action = "Index" });
```

I also have this in a view:

```
<link href="/css/Root/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The problem is that the `AssetController` does not invoke `Index` when `/css/Root/index.css` is requested. This is because a file actually exists at the path `/css/Root/index.css`.

If I recall correctly, there's a checkbox setting in IIS that basically says "Do not check that a file actually exists at the request path [instead, let the `RouteTable` handle it]." (At least there is in IIS 6.)

Is there something I can put in my Web.config that sets this IIS setting to `true`? How do I tell IIS to let my MVC routes handle the path even if a file exists at the path?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this site.  It helped me with the the same problem.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/